# Rails, add a trigger to update more than one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

[Following this guide here](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/wiki/Building-indexes), I want to add a trigger, that updates more than one attribute of a model. Here is what I have now:

```
class AddTriggerToArguments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  def up
    execute %{

  CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON arguments FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  tsvector_update_trigger(tsv_body, 'pg_catalog.simple', description);
 }
  end

  def down
    execute %{DROP TRIGGER tsvectorupdate ON arguments}

  end
end
```

As you can see in the line

```
tsvector_update_trigger(tsv_body, 'pg_catalog.simple', description);
```

updates the description attribute. But what do I have to do, so that multiple attributes will be updated?

My model has title and description as attributes. I want to add title to the trigger. I tried this, but it didnt work:

```
  def up
    execute %{

  CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON arguments FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  tsvector_update_trigger(tsv_body, 'pg_catalog.simple', description)
  tsvector_update_trigger(tsv_body, 'pg_catalog.simple', title);
     }
   end
```

But that didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  tsvector_update_trigger(tsv_body, 'pg_catalog.simple', description, title)
```

Seems to work.